# Static content for AWS EC2 with IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-cli

Reading through [the](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/details/manage-roles/) / [many](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx610S2MLVZWEA/Using-IAM-span-class-matches-roles-span-to-distribute-non-AWS-credentials-to-you) / [resources](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1XG3FX6VMU6O5/A-safer-way-to-distribute-AWS-credentials-to-EC2) on how to utilize temporary AWS credentials in a launched EC2 instance, I can't seem to get an extremely simple POC running.

**Desired:**

1. Launch an EC2 instance
2. SSH in
3. Pull a piece of static content from a private S3 bucket

**Steps:**

1. Create an `IAM` role
2. Spin up a new `EC2` instance with the above `IAM` role specified; `SSH` in
3. Set the credentials using `aws configure` and the details that (**successfully**) populated in `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/iam-role-name`
4. Attempt to use the `AWS CLI` directly to access the file

`IAM` role:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/file.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I use the `AWS CLI` to access the file, this error is thrown:

```
A client error (Forbidden) occurred when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
Completed 1 part(s) with ... file(s) remaining
```

Which step did I miss?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For future reference, the issue was in how I was calling the `AWS CLI`; previously I was running:

```
aws configure
```

...and supplying the details found in the auto-generated role profile.

Once I simply allowed it to find its own temporary credentials and just specified the only other required parameter manually (region):

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name/file.png file.png --region us-east-1
```

...the file pulled fine. Hopefully this'll help out someone in the future!

Comment: Thanks for this.  I was using this across 6 different regions, and in only one had to add `--region`  

Whatever, worked!

Answer (score 12):

Hope this might help some other Googler that lands here.

The

```
A client error (403) occurred when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

error can also be caused if your system clock is too far off.  I was 12 hours in the past and got this error.  Set the clock to within a minute of the true time, and error went away.

Answer (score 8):

According to [Granting Access to a Single S3 Bucket Using Amazon IAM](http://mikeferrier.com/2011/10/27/granting-access-to-a-single-s3-bucket-using-amazon-iam/), the IAM policy may need to be applied to two resources:

1. The bucket proper (e.g. "arn:aws:s3:::4ormat-knowledge-base")
2. All the objects inside the bucket (e.g. "arn:aws:s3:::4ormat-knowledge-base/*")

Yet another tripwire. Damn!

Comment: If you want to use `aws configure` with an IAM user's ID/key, this would appear to be the solution.  Here's a segment of the policy:

    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::yourbucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::yourbucket/*"
    ],

Answer (score 3):

I just got this error because I had an old version of awscli:

Broken:

`$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.2.9 Python/3.4.0 Linux/3.13.0-36-generic`

Works:

`$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.5.4 Python/3.4.0 Linux/3.13.0-36-generic`

Comment: How did you update the version? When I run sudo pip install awscli --upgrade it says that 1.2.9 version is the most up to date

Comment: I think `--upgrade` has to come before the package name.

Comment: This was the solution for me as well. Upgrading from ``aws-cli/1.3.11`` to ``aws-cli/1.10.2`` solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You also get this error if the key doesn't exist in the bucket.

Double-check the key -- I had a script that was adding an extra slash at the beginning of the key when it POSTed items into the bucket. So this:

```
aws s3 cp --region us-east-1 s3://bucketname/path/to/file /tmp/filename
```

failed with "A client error (Forbidden) occurred when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden."

But this:

```
aws s3 cp --region us-east-1 s3://bucketname//path/to/file /tmp/filename
```

worked just fine. Not a permissions issue at all, just boneheaded key creation.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error because I didn't attach a policy to my IAM user.

[image: How it should look]

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: wild card file globbing worked better in s3cmd for me.

As cool as aws-cli is --for my one-time S3 file manipulation issue that didn't immediately work as I would hope and thought it might-- I ended up installing and using s3cmd.

Whatever syntax and behind the scenes work I conceptually imagined, s3cmd was more intuitive and accomodating to my baked in preconceptions.

Maybe it isn't the answer you came here for, but it worked for me.